# Existe um equivalente do Scanner do Java no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Por enquanto estou apenas mexendo com o JavaScript no terminal. Existe algum método no JavaScript que tem uma função semelhante ao `Scanner` que existe no Java.

Comment: Como está a executar o codigo no terminal ? com node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe na implementação dos *browsers*. Elas são linguagens que implementam essas coisas em bibliotecas e não na linguagem em si. Java é usada prioritariamente como serviço de *backend*, console e GUI (menos), então faz sentido ter uma função que pede dados pelo console. JavaScript costuma ser usada em navegadores web e não faz sentido ter algo assim, mas pode ter algo que faça uma tarefa parecida (em Node ou outra implementação pode fazer sentido ter algo assim por rodar em console, veja o [`readline()`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)).

Em JavaScript tem o [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), que não pode ser considerado equivalente, apenas parecido, inclusive porque Java tenta avaliar o tipo de dado entrado e em JS isto não é feito, é problema do programador avaliar se a entrada de dados está dentro do que se espera em formato básico do tipo determinado (existem funções que ajudam). Java é uma linguagem de tipagem estática e isto é importante, em JS não.

Tem [alguma coisa para efeitos de depuração](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline.28.29), mas não se sei está disponível universalmente.

O mais comum é usar HTML para pedir uma informação sendo entrada, geralmente com uma *tag* [`<input "text">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). Aí terá que usar JS para pegar o dado digitado ali e fazer o que deseja (diversos exemplos pelo site aqui e [documentação de uma das funções](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).